# IBM ICP Manegment-Ingress

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

Cloud Private 2.1.0.3 fails starting management-ingress on Ubuntu 16.06 and 18.04
Docker.service was modified and service restarted

> LimitNOFILE=infinity
>   LimitNPROC=infinity
>   LimitCORE=infinity

The Docker ps command returns that the container is running

```
root@master-node:~# docker ps | grep management*
260419af796d        4b5ac3c6d7c5                   "/icp-management- 
ing…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        
k8s_icp-management-ingress_icp-management-ingress-t9jz7_kube- 
system_e31012fc-89e4-11e8-ba42-f46d043873f5_0
```

The Docker logs --follow reports no errors

```
root@master-node:~# docker logs --follow 260419af796d
I0717 17:14:44.989456       1 main.go:112] Creating API client for 
https://10.0.0.1:443
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ICP Management Ingress controller
Release:    UNKNOWN
Build:      UNKNOWN
Repository: UNKNOWN
----------------------------------------------------------------------
I0717 17:14:45.000195       1 main.go:125] Running in Kubernetes 
Cluster version v1.10 (v1.10.0+icp) - git (clean) commit 
1c6988c2361d678dab8ea5ddfab82cb52680b20b - platform linux/amd64
I0717 17:14:45.005428       1 nginx.go:204] starting Ingress 
controller
I0717 17:14:45.014718       1 event.go:218] 
Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kube-system", 
Name:"platform-oidc-block", UID:"dfafbcab-89e4-11e8-ba42- 
f46d043873f5", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"973", 
FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress kube- 
system/platform-oidc-block
I0717 17:14:45.014922       1 event.go:218] 
Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kube-system", 
Name:"id-mgmt", UID:"dfb16986-89e4-11e8-ba42-f46d043873f5", 
APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"979", FieldPath:""}): type: 
'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress kube-system/id-mgmt
I0717 17:14:45.015009       1 event.go:218] 
Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kube-system", 
Name:"platform-oidc", UID:"dfaf5fdd-89e4-11e8-ba42-f46d043873f5", 
APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"971", FieldPath:""}): type: 
'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress kube-system/platform-oidc
I0717 17:14:45.015178       1 event.go:218] 
Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kube-system", 
Name:"platform-auth", UID:"dfb220bf-89e4-11e8-ba42-f46d043873f5", 
APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"981", FieldPath:""}): type: 
'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress kube-system/platform-auth
I0717 17:14:45.015306       1 event.go:218] 
Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"kube-system", 
Name:"iam-pap", UID:"e12bcbfc-89e4-11e8-ba42-f46d043873f5", 
APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"1046", FieldPath:""}): type:       
Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress kube-system/iam-pap
I0717 17:14:45.015398       1 event.go:218]
```

After 100 retires it dies
SUSE did not present same same error on same hardware
Both 16.04 and 18.04 do

EDIT more information:
so the step that it is doing is

```
kubectl -n kube-system get daemonset icp-management-ingress -o=custom-     columns=A:.status.numberAvailable,B:.status.desiredNumberScheduled --no-  headers=true | tr -s \" \" | awk '$1 == $2 {print \"READY\"}'"
```

when I run this via cmd line
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "daemonset"

Comment: UPDATE #2 I moved back to version 2.1.0.2 after uninstall of 2.1.0.3 and all worked fine. I will report to dev guys to see if they seen this.

Comment: Reposting comment from @Rachid: *Let me check with our devsquad and get back to you.*

Answer (score 0):

I did not see explicit error message from the log. And also from output of 'docker ps | grep management', the service was running for an hour.

The 'kubectl' command you were running is not correct. It should be

`kubectl -n kube-system get ds icp-management-ingress`